# Two forms with submit buttons two different functions. One button to run a javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Form1 has the action to link to an external .aspx file. But once I added Form2 and the javascript file, contact-us/js/app.js, to the page. The javascript now controlls both form submit buttons. How do I link the javascript file to only run when Form2 button is submitted?

```
Form1
<div id="guestLogin">
<form id="frmguestlogin" name="frmguestlogin" method="post" action="AutoLogin.aspx" >
<input type="hidden" name="username" class="text" id="username" onfocus="this.value='';" tabindex="30" value="guest" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" class="text" id="password" onfocus="this.value='';" tabindex="40" value="guest" />
<input type="submit" width="80" height="20" border="0" name="submit" id="submit" value="Guest Login" tabindex="50" />
</form>
</div>
```

Form2 code. The last script is controlling both submit buttons on the page. How do I only have it control Form2 submit button?

```
Form2
<div id="form-wrapper">
<div class="inner cover">
<form class="form-signin" id="form-signin"  >
<h4 class="sendMsg">Send us a message</h4>
<input type="text" id="first" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input type="text" id="last" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required >
<input type="text" id="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" required >
<input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required >
<input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required >
<p> Tell us how we can help you</p>
<textarea id="comments" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" class="form-control" cols="45" rows="5" required ></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Send Your Message</button>
<input id="subject" name="subject" type="hidden" value="Contact Us" />

</form>

</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="contact-us/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="contact-us/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<script src="contact-us/js/app.js"></script>
```

app.js code to control form2 only:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //Submit Form
    var first = $("input#first").val();
    var last = $("input#last").val();
    var company = $("input#company").val();
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var comments = $("textarea#comments").val();
    var subject = $("input#subject").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact-us.asp",
        data: { first : first,
                last : last,
                company : company,
                phone : phone,
                email : email,
                comments : comments,
                subject : subject },
                cache : false,
                contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function() {
            $('.form-signin').hide();
            $('.cover').fadeIn('slow').html('<h2>Thank You, '+first+' '+last+'</h2>');
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: What did you try? Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: I want to have the script contact-us/js/app.js only control form2. it is controlling form1 and two when the submit buttons are clicked.

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the contents of your custom (not Bootstrap or JQuery) JavaScripts. We don't know what they are unless we can read them.

Comment: @Cory J. - I'm sorry. I don't think I'm explaining it correctly... Both form1 and form2 are on the same html page. The <script src="contact-us/js/app.js"></script> is controlling both my submit buttons on the page. I only want <script src="contact-us/js/app.js"></script> to control form2 and I want to leave form1 to use the action="AutoLogin.aspx" but since they are on the same page app.js script is controlling both submit buttons. How do I get form2 to only run the app.js script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To route it with a certain script (without a form submit) I would use a normal button type.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
```

The onclick calls the JavaScript function that contains what you want it to do.

Edited - Added notes:
Also this calls just a form in general

> $("form").submit

It doesn't specify what form it is, use an ID to find the 2nd form

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form2").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Form 1</h1>
Form one goes to aspx.

<form action="AutoLogin.aspx">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<h1>Form 2</h1>

Form two goes to the JQuery based off of the form ID (this works with external files as well)
<form id="form2">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: the javascript is a separate linked file: <script src="contact-us/js/app.js"></script>. How do I get form2 submit button to link to that script on the page?

Comment: You have already got it linked at the bottom of the form2 section you provided, the form 2 has a unique id from form one

<form class="form-signin" id="form-signin"  >

so in your $("form").submit I would put $("#form-signin").submit

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I'm explaining it correctly... Both form1 and form2 are on the same html page. The <script src="contact-us/js/app.js"></script> is controlling both my submit buttons on the page. I only want <script src="contact-us/js/app.js"></script> to control form2 and I want to leave form1 to use the action="AutoLogin.aspx" but since they are on the same page app.js script is controlling both submit buttons. How do I get form2 to only run the app.js script?

Comment: Updated my Answer up above (im a little new to this, not sure if it notifies you)

Comment: I don't need a pop-up to confirm the form being submitted. I need the script contact-us/app.js to only control form2 submit button, but it's controlling form1. Is there a way to write a script for form2 to be controlled by the script contact-us/app.js (external file not on the html page).

Comment: in your app.js code
change 
$("form").submit(function(e) {
to
$("#form-signin").submit(function(e) {

Comment: That worked!! Hip Hip Hooray. Thank you so much Adam for helping me with this. I appreciate it tremendously.

Comment: Glad to be of some help :)